# Loading multiple slideshows one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used Wordpress with a slideshow plugin called cyclone slider. I have built the website as one page only, so all the pages along with the slideshows are stacked with `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` and on click to `z-index`, `visibility: visible` and `display: block`.

The site loads extremely slow obviously as there are a lot of slideshows with images averaging 100kb in size, its a photographers website and he does not want to optimize the images anymore.

How could I use `jQuery` to only load images on every slideshow once its parent goes from `display: none`  to `display: block` or from `visibility: hidden` to visible. or even using `z-index`.

The best option would be if you click on another category, it starts loading that catagory or section slideshow and then stops loading the slideshow you were just on.

Some layout code:

```
<div id="togglelinks" class="gallery-toggle">
<ul>
  <li class="people"><a class="switch" href="#" data-toggle="#people"><i>People</i></a></li>
  <li class="business"><a class="switch" href="#" data-toggle="#business"><i>People</i></a></li>
  <li class="school"><a class="switch" href="#" data-toggle="#school"><i>People</i></a></li>                                
</ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="catagories">
    <div class="people cat-main">
      <div id="people" class="landing-cat" style="display:block; visibility:visible;">
        <div class="slider"><?php if( function_exists('cyclone_slider') ) cyclone_slider('people'); ?></div>
      </div>
      <div id="business" class="sub-cata hide" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
        <div class="slider"><?php if( function_exists('cyclone_slider') ) cyclone_slider('business'); ?></div>
      </div>
      <div id="school" class="sub-cata hide" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
        <div class="slider"><?php if( function_exists('cyclone_slider') ) cyclone_slider('school'); ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [JQuery LazyLoad plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

Another, more hands-on approach would be something along the lines of:

1. On first load, create tags for all images. For loaded images provide src attribute, for later-loaded images provide the src in a different attribute.
2. bind an event to viewing an image (scroll \ click)
3. when the event fires, find the next image, get the alternative src attribute and plug it into the src attribute.